# best jQuery Swipe to slide for touch screen devices

Tags: jquery, ios, ipad, tablet, swipe

I've been looking around the net and on this board for a really good jQuery version of the Swipe to horizontal scroll like apple has on their website, http://www.apple.com/ipad/ios

If you view the website on an iPad (I think other touch devices will work the same also) their swipe gallery works beautifully (under the section The worlds largest collection of mobile apps on apples site)

Everywhere I've seen so far doesn't seem to support a gallery with such fluidity, can anyone suggest a jQuery plugin or code?  I've been having lots of difficulty finding a jQuery plugin since they pulled that part of their website offline.

Answer (score 1):

Best one I've used:
http://www.photoswipe.com/

EDIT: you can test it on this site: http://islastudio.com/mobile/photos

Comment: Thanks for this however it doesn't seem to be able to support the swipe across gallery like on Apple's site. I have a horizontal gallery bar in the middle of the page just like on Apple's site but I'm using jQuery on the rest of my page and the js libraries is just no compatible on the same page as jQuery so I must use a jQuery library which can do the same thing.  If you know any other, please let me know :D

Answer (score 0):

http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

Flexslider is an awesome, fully responsive jQuery slider toolkit. Features include:

- Hardware accelerated touch swipe support
- Simple, semantic markup
- Supported in all major browsers
- Horizontal/vertical slide and fade animations
- Multiple slider support, Callback API, and more
- Custom navigation options
- Compatible with the latest version of jQuery

With it, you can recreate Apple's iPad page, and much much more. And it's rather simple to set up.